# How to highlight the most recent table row in datatables

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datatable

I am creating a table row using

```
mytable.row.add(getTableRow(data.report)).draw();


function getTableRow(report) {
    var id = report.id;
    var date = report.create_date;
    return [
        "<a href=\"/date/" + id + "\">" + date + "</a>",
        user
    ];
}
```

How can I highlight the table row as soon as I draw it?

Here is my table structure

```
      <table class="table-bordered" id="mytableid" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="20%">Date</th>
                <th width="20%">User</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
            <span> </span>
            Loading...
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a nicer solution. Take advantage of dataTables [**`to$()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/to$()) method, that make you work on the internal nodes as jQuery objects, and use a javascript [**`with`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement to both add a `.newRow` class and `draw()` the new row :

```js
with (mytable.row.add(getTableRow(data.report))) {
   nodes().to$().addClass('newRow')
   draw()
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hzvskp77/**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#yourTableId tr.highlight').removeClass('highlight'); //remove any pre existing class
$('#yourTableId tr a.latest').removeClass('latest'); //remove class from any exiting anchor tag

mytable.row.add(getTableRow(data.report)).draw();

$('#yourTableId tr a.latest').closest('tr').addClass('highlight');  

function getTableRow(report) {
    var id = report.id;
    var date = report.create_date;
    return [
        "<a href=\"/date/" + id + "\" class="latest">" + date + "</a>",
        user
    ];
}
```

Also have this CSS rule

```
tr.highlight td{
 background-color: yellow;
 color:black;
}
```

Idea is to set a class to the anchor tag say `latest` and once the table is redrawn find this anchor tag with this class and then traverse to its 'tr' and add a class called `highlight`. For this class we have the CSS which will change the look of this tr.

---

**Edit 1:** You need to wait for the table to complete the draw and then add the highlight class. So use this syntax.

```
$('#myTable ').dataTable( {
    // other stuff
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
         $('#myTable tr a.latest').closest('tr').addClass('highlight'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this with your css but it did not work`$('#myTable tr.highlight').removeClass('highlight'); 
    $('#myTable tr a.latest').removeClass('latest');     myTable.row.add(getTableRow(data.report)).draw();
    $('#myTable tr a.latest').closest('tr').addClass('highlight'); ` with `function getTableRow(report) {
 var id = report.id;
 var date = report.create_date;

 return [
  "<a href=\"/reports/" + id + "\">" + date + "</a>",
  user
 ];`

Comment: @lovesoftlayeraj updated my answer. have a check, you need to add this `drawCallback` while initializing the datatables plugin.

Comment: Problem is I have already initialized the data table when I load the page. (I tried adding your function there). and then when I create a row I just do `myTable.row.add(getTableRow(data.report)).draw();` and then does not go back to the datatable initialisation function.

Comment: If I know the row index how I can I add highlight class to a row of mytable?  I  just want to highlight the topmost row of my table

Comment: any time the table is drawn again using `draw()` just like you are doing `myTable.row.add(getTableRow(data.report)).draw();` it will execute that call back function.

Comment: @lovesoftlayeraj if you know rowindex then you can do `$('#myTable tr:eq(' + rowIndex+')').addClass('highlight');`

Comment: I got syntax error missing bracket `$('#mytable tr:eq('0')').addClass('highlight');` and `$('#myTable tr:eq(0)').addClass('highlight');` did not work though syntax is correct

Comment: @lovesoftlayeraj the syntax you have mentioned must work 100%, unless its not executed, or if you have not added the CSS .. if you just execute that script in your console window you must be able to see it working...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108831/discussion-between-lovesoftlayeraj-and-reddy).